# memcached on PHP AWS Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, memcached, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I need to use Memcache (or memcached) on my PHP Beanstalk Deployment.

I looked at `phpinfo()` and i got that memcached is installed as php extension.

[image]

[image]

But it fails everytime I try to connect

```
$memcache = new Memcached();
$memcache->AddServer("127.0.0.1",11211)  // returns false
```

What shoud I do?

PS I dont want to use  AWS elasticache, I need local memory cache.

Comment: Your phpinfo() indicates your beanstalk has the php library to connect to memcached - that is not the same as having memcached service installed on your server. I suspect you will need to customise your stack and install memecached - as its aws' intention to point users toward elasticache it doesnt seem likely the memcached would be running it the stock Php configuration.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?  I seem to be able to connect to memcached but then get a warning `PHP Warning:  Memcached::setMulti(): failed to set key .../var/app/current/vendor/symfony/cache/Traits/MemcachedTrait.php on line 242`. Pls advise